# Google Authentication for tktiner/discord/rails app

Tags: python, authentication, google-oauth

## Background info

I'm currently in the process of making a system that tracks work sessions, and the shifts done by people in those sessions. It will consist of a discord bot for alerts and responses to invites, a python app for initiating these sessions & invites, and eventually a rails web app for everything. Users will log on with their google accounts. MySQL database currently stores all the data.

## Question

I want to make it so my python script (and eventually web app) users can log on using their Google accounts. What's the simplest use of OAuth2 to just get the user's email? The SQL database has their email and it would be nice to just have some simple call to the Google API that returns the email of the user, so I can cross-reference that with my user table to find which user is logging on.

## Also...

This isn't just me being lazy and wanting someone else to give me the code for this project, I've actually done Google authentication before with accessing spreadsheets shared with users, however in this example I feel as though it could be simplified as I don't need access to any of the user's Google account, just which email they used to sign in, and I can't find a way myself.

Comment: Show us what you have done before and we will change it together.

Comment: @ElisByberi Before I was using SHA512 hash on passwords with a heavy disclaimer that the user's passwords are not stored in a very good way. Didn't bother mentioning it because it obviously all has to go.